# Where does Internet Explorer store information about the default homepage?

Tags: internet, windows-explorer, internet-explorer

By that I mean, where on the hard drive does IE store information about the default homepage?

Comment: it is in registry key value. not easily accessible on the file level.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main, key “Start Page”=”http://www.somewhere.com/”